# How can I count number of times a loop iterates and put that as a value in a dataframe column?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 3 columns, which categorizes if column A is greater than column B.

```
dataf <- data.frame(category = c("Above", "Below", "In Range", "Above"),
                    A = c(1.99, 4.99, 6.99, 5.99),
                    B = c(0.99, 9.99, 6.99, 1.99))
```

The goal is to create a new column with the following logic:

**If category = "Above"**, calculate the number of times we would decrease A to be less than B times 1.1 if we have a maximum change amount of 20%
**If category = "Below"**, calculate the number of times we would increase A to be equal to or greater than B if we have a maximum change amount of 20%
**If category = "In Range"**, record 0 changes

I want to record this in a new column of dataf.

The desired output would look like:

```
desired_dataf <- data.frame(category = c("Above", "Below", "In Range", "Above"),
A = c(1.99, 4.99, 6.99, 5.99),
B = c(0.99, 9.99, 6.99, 1.99),
C = c(3, 4, 0, 5))
```

This is my attempt at solving this problem:

```
dataf <- data.frame(category = c("Above", "Below", "In Range", "Above"),
                    A = c(1.99, 4.99, 6.99, 3.99),
                    B = c(0.99, 7.99, 6.99, 1.99))

decrease_func <- function(x, y, count=0, max=1.1) {
  new_x <- x
  while((new_x/y) > max) {
    new_x = new_x * (.8)
    count = count + 1
  }
  return(count)
}

increase_func <- function(x, y, count=0, min=1.0) {
  new_x <- x
  while((new_x / y) < min) {
    new_x = new_x * (1.2)
    count = count + 1
  }
  return(count)
}

new_df <- dataf %>%
  mutate(new_col = case_when(category == "Above" ~ decrease_func(A,B),
  category == "Below" ~ increase_func(A,B),
  TRUE ~ 0))

new_df
```

But running it gives me this error:

```
Error in mutate(., new_col = case_when(category == "Above" ~ decrease_func(A,  : 
  
Caused by error in `case_when()`:
! Failed to evaluate the right-hand side of formula 1.
Caused by error in `while ((new_x / y) > max) {
    new_x = new_x * (0.8)
    count = count + 1
  }`:
! the condition has length > 1
```

Testing these functions outside of the dataframe works correctly.

```
decrease_func(1.99, .99)

increase_func(4.99, 9.99)

decrease_func(5.99, 1.99
```

Output:

> [1] 3
> [1] 4
> [1] 5

I am guessing it is a problem with trying to use a while loop in mutate? Is there a better way to accomplish this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try running your test with, say, `decrease_func(c(1.99, 4.99, 6.99, 3.99), c(0.99, 7.99, 6.99, 1.99))`.  Your current test does not replicate your actual use conditions.

Comment: A simple (non-optimal, not recommended) solution to get your code to run is to insert `%>% rowwise()` in the pipe that creates `new_df`.  But this does not produce your desired output.  I think your functions may use faulty logic, but I do not have time to explore further.  I suspect that it should be possible to calculate the required number of "iterations" without resorting to a loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true for all numbers. What if there is no correct solution? eg `x = 1; y=0.58` there is no number of times you will reduce x by 20% to get to within 10%  of y. ie if you run `decrease_func(1, 0.58)` it gives you 2 as the solution. But reducing x twice by 20% gives you 0.64 which is `10.34%` away from 0.58. If you try 3 times, you get 0.512 which is 11.72% away from 0.58. So with the given example, no solution exists. But of course we could take `2` since 10.34 is closer though not within 10%.

Mathematically we could solve the equation as:

```
fn <- function(x,y, change = 0.2){
    round(log(y/x)/log((1 - change * ((x > y) - (x < y)))))
}
transform(dataf, new_col = fn(A, B))
  category    A    B new_col
1    Above 1.99 0.99       3
2    Below 4.99 9.99       4
3 In Range 6.99 6.98       0
4    Above 5.99 1.99       5
```

Note that this will give the desired solution. So why did we not check whether its within 10%? You should. and that changes the function abit:

```
fn <- function(x,y, change = 0.2, within = 0.1){
    z <- y %o% (1 + within * c(-1,1))
    d <- (1 - change * ((x > y) - (x < y)))
    r <- round(log(z/x)/log(d))
    idx <- r[,1] == r[,2]
    neg_idx <- !idx
    res <- numeric(length(x))
    res[idx] <- r[idx, 1]
    e <- abs(x[neg_idx] * d[neg_idx]^r[neg_idx,] - y[neg_idx])/y[neg_idx]
    res[neg_idx] <- r[neg_idx,][cbind(seq(sum(neg_idx)), max.col(-e))]
    res
}

transform(dataf, new_col = fn(A, B))
 category    A    B new_col
1    Above 1.99 0.99       3
2    Below 4.99 9.99       4
3 In Range 6.99 6.98       0
4    Above 5.99 1.99       5
```

Comment: That makes sense and I appreciate you pointing that out. I was mistaken in how I explained the goal, in the example you mentioned I would end the count after it crosses the 1 + 10% threshold or goes above 1.0 if x < y. For my use case using ceiling() instead of round() will do the trick. Thank you very much for your reply to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Analysing the problem with some algebra, I came up with this solution:

```
fun <- function(x1, x2) {
    less <- x1 < x2
    base <- c(0.8, 1.2)[less + 1]
    ordr <- cbind(less, !less)
    mat <- cbind(lo=logb((0.9*x2)/x1, base),
                 hi=logb((1.1*x2)/x1, base))
    mat[] <- cbind(ceiling(rowSums(mat*ordr)), floor(rowSums(mat*!ordr)))
    apply(mat, 1, function(x) x[1]:x[2])
}

dataf <- data.frame(category = c("Above", "Below", "In Range", "Above"),
                    A = c(1.99, 4.99, 6.99, 5.99),
                    B = c(0.99, 9.99, 6.99, 1.99))

transform(dataf, C=fun(A, B))
#   category    A    B C
# 1    Above 1.99 0.99 3
# 2    Below 4.99 9.99 4
# 3 In Range 6.99 6.99 0
# 4    Above 5.99 1.99 5
```

---

#### More detailed working out

First a simplified version where you either multiply the first value successively with 0.8 until it's less than the second value, or you multiply the first value successively with 1.2 until it's greater than the second value.

```
# When x1 is larger than x2

x1 <- 2
x2 <- 1

which(x1*cumprod(rep(0.8, 6)) < x2)[1]
# [1] 4

x1*(0.8^4) < x2
# [1] TRUE

n <- 4

x1*(0.8^n) < x2
# [1] TRUE

0.8^n < x2/x1
# [1] TRUE

n*log(0.8) < log(x2/x1)
# [1] TRUE

n > log(x2/x1)/log(0.8) # log(0.8) is negative, switch inequality sign
# [1] TRUE

n > logb(x2/x1, base=0.8)
# [1] TRUE



# When x1 is smaller than x2

x1 <- 1
x2 <- 2

which(x1*cumprod(rep(1.2, 6)) > x2)[1]
# [1] 4

x1*(1.2^4) > x2
# [1] TRUE

n <- 4

x1*(1.2^n) > x2
# [1] TRUE

1.2^n > x2/x1
# [1] TRUE

n*log(1.2) > log(x2/x1)
# [1] TRUE

n > log(x2/x1)/log(1.2)
# [1] TRUE

n > logb(x2/x1, base=1.2)
# [1] TRUE


# Test the algorithm

x1 <- c(1, 2, 1.5, 0.5, 1)
x2 <- c(2, 1, 0.5, 1.5, 1)

base <- c(0.8, 1.2)[(x1 < x2) + 1]

ceiling(logb(x2/x1, base))
# [1] 4 4 5 7 0
```

Looks good so far. Then the slightly more complicated version where we want to find out how many times to multiply the first value with 0.8 or 1.2 until it's within 10% of the second value. It ends up with a similar set of equations to the first one, but because we lose some symmetry, the final algorithm requires a bit of extra work.

```
x1 <- 2
x2 <- 1

abs(x1*cumprod(rep(0.8, 6)) - x2) < 0.1*x2
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

n <- 3

abs(x1*(0.8^n) - x2) < 0.1*x2
# [1] TRUE

-0.1*x2 < x1*(0.8^n)-x2 & x1*(0.8^n)-x2 < 0.1*x2
# [1] TRUE

(0.9*x2)/x1 < 0.8^n & 0.8^n < (1.1*x2)/x1
# [1] TRUE

logb((0.9*x2)/x1, 0.8) > n & n > logb((1.1*x2)/x1, 0.8)
# [1] TRUE


# When x1 is smaller than x2

x1 <- 1
x2 <- 2

n <- 4

logb((0.9*x2)/x1, 1.2) < n & n < logb((1.1*x2)/x1, 1.2)
# [1] TRUE

# Putting together an algorithm

x1 <- c(1, 2, 1.5, 0.5, 1)
x2 <- c(2, 1, 0.5, 1.5, 1)

less <- x1 < x2
base <- c(0.8, 1.2)[less + 1]
ordr <- cbind(less, !less)
mat <- cbind(lo=logb((0.9*x2)/x1, base),
             hi=logb((1.1*x2)/x1, base))
mat[] <- cbind(ceiling(rowSums(mat*ordr)), floor(rowSums(mat*!ordr)))
apply(mat, 1, function(x) x[1]:x[2])
# [1] 4 3 5 6 0
```

Seems to work again, though I'm sure more skilled mathematicians can find some areas of improvement.